# IIS Serving Child Application before hitting Parent Application Pipeline

Tags: authentication, iis, reverse-proxy, staging

I have a parent ASP.NET Application which is supposed to provide restricted access via login (in-app login not *IIS Authentication*). Parent app is an MVC app (or razor pages) and it is defined as **IIS WebSite**, which is the same as **IIS Application**. I have restricted access to everything under /Run route as in:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Run", "/");
        });
```

The child application is deployed as a child **IIS Application** under the *Parent Site*.

Whatever URL I type that is under **mysite.com/run/???** is successfully redirected to login page since it needs authorization. But when I type the URL of the child app (mysite.com/run/demo), IIS immediately starts loading it without hitting the parent sites logic/pipeline. When IIS sees a virtual directory/application it serves it immediately. I want it to go through my parent app first.

Is there anyway I can make IIS to go through my parent app runtime?

(if the answer is implementing a reverse proxy how exactly? Where am I going to redirect the requests to?)

Comment: Applications under the same site are isolated from each other and run separately, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis So there is no "child application" or "parent application" and their initialization time spots do not depend on each other. You need a SSO solution, not reverse proxy.

Comment: But I don't want to be "signed-in" under the "child application". I want it to be completely unaccessible. I will appreciate anything I can read about it. Thanks.

Comment: So you want the two applications to use different login?

Comment: Yes / I don't care. I want the mvc app in the parent site to control access to child apps. When IIS receives a request and finds a virtual directory/application there it immideately serves it without hitting my parent website routes.

Comment: @Lex Li and fyi the msdn documentation you referred to indeed makes use of the concept "parent site" as in paragraph 17: "For an application to communicate by using a protocol that is specified in the parent site's binding, you must enable the protocol".